# How many times SDP protocol is passed in a video call

Tags: webrtc, sdp

1)In webrtc at initial state we pass sdp protocol between peers to establish a connection.Does it happen only once or it happens through out the call process?

2)How does it calculate the peers bandwidth?Can we change it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDP for video is passed only once, exactly the same way as for an audio-only call. You can suggest bandwidth with the SDP and depending on the codec it might also change at run-time, there is no need for extra SDP exchange for this.

SDP can be exchanged also multiple times during a session, but this is only for special functionality if you need to change the media parameters such as re-invite with different codec, hold/reload or conference.